# Having a really hard time getting OAuth2.0 token. Keep getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-api

```
       /*WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    string parameters = "code=4/f2PwqbN1Z5FpEEcT0scRH20B6d-F.ouqZIhzZqUYbEnp6UAPFm0EuJPwSigI&" +
        "client_id=162438320977-ml14ajmuutlrr71maal933ma5cjolc8l.apps.googleusercontent.com&" +
        "&client_secret=1IJxvSnmxcx-i2l_YGgYOD0i&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code";

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);
    var test = client.UploadData("http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","POST", data);
    string result = data.ToString();*/

    StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder();
    parameters.Append("code=4/IoAJMoYxUqk7lkH_WbSr3lk4URf1.0t7Qx7qZE5QeEnp6UAPFm0G0EvMSigI");
    parameters.Append("&client_id=162438320977-ml14ajmuutlrr71maal933ma5cjolc8l.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    parameters.Append("&client_secret=1IJxvSnmxcx-i2l_YGgYOD0i");
    parameters.Append("&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
    parameters.Append("&grant_type=authorization_code");

    string p_params = parameters.ToString();
    byte[] p_data_params = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p_params);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = p_data_params.Length;

    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(p_data_params, 0, p_data_params.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

The only approach that seems to work for me is using HttpWebRequest. I found the answer here: [.Net Google OAuth token WebRequest Bad Request Protocol Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696584/net-google-oauth-token-webrequest-bad-request-protocol-error?rq=1) If anyone knows of a way to get the Web Client implementation working please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use the client API just to get the auth token, but then make the post yourself?

Comment: I'm a little concerned if I'm unable to get the auth token that I won't be very successful in other POSTs.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @RyanTorrence: Well in my experience, doing the initial OAuth2 dance is the hardest bit :)

Comment: Well I would still like to be able to figure out a way to get this to work.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was able to get it working using HttpWebRequest but it doesn't seem that it wants to work with web client. Any ideas?

Comment: @RyanTorrence: I suggest you edit your post to include all that information (and probably get rid of the comment parts, which aren't terribly useful).

Comment: @JonSkeet Alright I updated my post and just kept some information regarding the WebClient which doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: Have you tried using `UploadValues` instead of `UploadData`? And have you used something like Wireshark to see what the network traffic looks like? Also note that you're using https with WebRequest, but http with WebClient.

Comment: @JonSkeet I figured it out. I changed redirect_uri to "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" from http://localhost. Not really sure why this works though.

Comment: @RyanTorrence hi i have the same issue. Would you share your answer?